# Почему Apache возвращает forbidden?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

В корне сайта нет файла `.htaccess` , присутствует `index.php`. Почему при запросе на сайт возникает 403 ошибка?
Права на все папки - 755, на все файлы - 644, владелец - root

 Стоит php 7.0.20 

 **Конфиги апач**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com.ua

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www_myserver.com.ua

<Directory /var/www_myserver.com.ua>
#   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#        AllowOverride all #Deprecated
#        Order allow,deny #Deprecated
#        Allow from all #Deprecater
#   Require all granted
</Directory>


    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot /var/www_myserver.com.ua
ServerName myserver.com.ua

#SSLEngine on
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

<Directory /var/www_myserver.com.ua>
#   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#   AllowOverride all #Deprecated
#   Order allow,deny #Deprecated
#   Allow from all #Deprecated
#   Require all granted #Deprecated
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Дополнил конфиги, попробовал рестартануть апач, выдает ошибку:

```
Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

failed!
Комманда `systemctl status apache2.service` выдает:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-11 17:36:38 EEST; 2min 3s ago
  Process: 1407 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: Output of config test was:
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-web8.teamgear.conf:
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: Illegal override option #Deprecated
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 apache2[1407]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 11 17:36:38 web21 systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Сам index.php открывается? Если да, то просто не настроен DirectoryIndex . А вот если нет, то где-то в конфиге апача запрещено показывать эту директорию.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Сам index.php не открывается, на любые попытки достучаться до сервака приходит 403 ошибка, конфиги апача могу закинуть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте что-то вроде

```
<Directory "/var/www/example_site_directory">
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

в конфиге хоста. А то у вас все опции закомментированы. Это если у вас apache 2.4

Comment: Сейчас попробую)

Comment: Теперь сайт вообще лёг, дополню сейчас вопрос, не стартует апач

Comment: Смотрите логи апача. И укажите версию апача. Похоже у вас 2.2

Comment: Как проверить версию апача?

Comment: `apache2 -v` в консоле или через phpinfo()

Comment: `Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)`

Comment: закомментируйте `AllowOverride All ` - что получится?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, апач лежит

Comment: в сообщениях об ошибке в логах есть изменения?

Comment: Нет, изменения не появляются

Comment: То есть у нас та же ошибка `AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-web8.teamgear.conf:` - что на этой строке написано?

Comment: Require all granted

Comment: Словом, вся беда была в #Deprecated, которые раскиданы по конфигу. Меньше надо было мне копипастить =) Спасибо за помощь.